# How to set Monday as first day of week in wijmo calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar, globalization, wijmo

I’m using wijmo calendar open and I can’t find a way of setting Monday as first day of the week.
Can someone help me achieve this please?

Answer (score 2):

Wijmo relays (in terms of internationalization) on https://github.com/jquery/globalize.

To the options of wijmo.datepicker you can pass cultureID which corresponds to any culture defined here https://github.com/jquery/globalize/tree/master/lib/cultures.

The value that you're looking for is `firstDay` attribute (it is defined in every culture). Its value corresponds to the index of a day, in a list of days, that will be assumed as first day of the week. firstDay is set to `0` to set Sunday as first day, and have to be set to `1` to make Monday a first day of the week.

For example to set the *culture* to Polish (for which first day of the week is acutally monday), you have to do something like this:

```
$(".selector").wijcalendar({
    culture: "pl-PL"
});
```

Comment: Yes that could be one of the solution but I don't want to pollute my code with workarounds. The nice people at wijmo suggested another cleaner solution ["Set Monday as first day"](http://wijmo.com/groups/community/forum/topic/how-to-set-monday-as-first-day-of-week/) if anybody have this problem. Thanks anyway.